# Angular don't detect route params change

Tags: angular, angular-router

my Angular project don't detect if I with navigate change the params.

```
   this.router.navigate(['data', id, scope]);
```

this is my router (this is a child module):

```
const routes: Routes = [{
path: ':id', component: DataComponent, children: [
  { path: 'info',  loadChildren: () => import(`./info-module/info-module.module`).then(m => m.InfoModuleModule) },
  { path: ':scope',  loadChildren: () => import(`./data-dashboard-module/data-dashboard-module.module`).then(m => m.DataDashboardModuleModule) },

] }];
```

If I change the param "scope" nothing happen, If I go to the route "info" it work.

Some solution?

Comment: I don't see the `data` in your router config

Comment: `this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe`?

Comment: Though the comment by @Pieterjan is not clear, you need to subscribe to the params and take the appropriate action when changed

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I resolved it by creating a Behaviour Subject for the id & subscribed it in the component. This will detect the change on every value change of the id/ object or anthing that u want to change in the route.

This should resolve the issue.

Comment: yeah it could work but it’s like a workaround and is not so elegant , it seems strange that is not possible to just force refresh the route